# open jdk 7 for ubuntu 10.04 from quantal repo

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I've successfully installed openjdk 7 and tomcat7 on ubuntu 10.04 using repo for ubuntu 12.10, everything seems to work fine, but I realize that this is not the way I supposed to get sofware for old releases of OS) So, the question is, has someone ever tried to perform the same action (I'm pretty sure someone has) and what were the repercussions in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't follow this approach since you're installing packages manually, which is no better than downloading Oracle's JDK and Tomcat separately and installing them on `/opt`

I can think of two better options:

1. Installing openjdk6 and tomcat6, which are available on 10.04 already. It's very likely you don't need the latest versions of both. Check if any of the web apps you want to deploy actually **requires** Java 7 and Tomcat 7.
2. Install OpenJDK7 and Tomcat7 from a PPA. I found that there's a [PPA for OpenJDK which packages openjdk7 for Lucid](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid), so it's likely you'll find another for Tomcat. The advantage of this is that you'll have updates and security patches.

Also, consider upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, which contains all of the above, but already integrated. I haven't upgraded Ubuntu server myself, but I've read it's safe and straightforward.